# SQL Server process time running and ip address

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to make a `SELECT` or stored procedure to find out how long are running one process and from where (ip adress).

```
SELECT 
   conn.session_ID as SPID,
   conn.client_net_address as IPAddress,
   sess.host_name as MachineName,
   sess.program_name as ApplicationName,
   login_name as LoginName
FROM 
   sys.dm_exec_connections conn
INNER JOIN 
   sys.dm_exec_sessions sess ON conn.session_ID = sess.session_ID
```

I have this but only the ip adress is being displayed.

Comment: Looks like you have 4 other columns besides IP address there. What are you trying to do and what is not doing what you want?

Comment: I want to find how long time is running a process/session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add

```
sess.last_request_start_time,
sess.last_request_end_time,
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176013.aspx

You can use DATEDIFF to get a number of seconds between the dates and ISNULL to substitute the current time for the end time if last request hasn't ended.

```
SELECT 
conn.session_ID as SPID,
conn.client_net_address as IPAddress,
sess.host_name as MachineName,
sess.program_name as ApplicationName,
login_name as LoginName,
sess.last_request_start_time,sess.last_request_end_time,
DATEDIFF(second,sess.last_request_start_time,ISNULL(sess.last_request_end_time,getdate())) last_request_seconds
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections conn
inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions sess
on conn.session_ID=sess.session_ID
WHERE conn.session_ID <> @@SPID -- Don't include this query
```